# Passing url parameters?

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

I have a servlet that basically accepts firstname and lastname in a html page and displays it.

I am trying to compose a URL in your browser address bar that will set firstname to x and lastname to y.

I tried this url but it is not working.

http://localhost:51500/examples/servlets/servlet/RequestParamExample/?firstname=%22+x+%22&lastname=%22+y

Not sure what i am doing wrong?

Comment: In what way is it "not working"? What happens when you test it?

Comment: HTTP Status 404 - /examples/servlets/servlet/RequestParamExample/     type Status report

message /examples/servlets/servlet/RequestParamExample/

description The requested resource is not available.

Comment: That is what is displayed. This is on a server at work and I am trying to send in the x and y parameters thru the url. I get that error everytime. I am tunneled into the server.

Comment: It's not your query string that's the problem then. http://localhost:51500/examples/servlets/servlet/RequestParamExample/ wouldn't work either. It's probably your servlet mappings - troubleshoot that first, then start testing the query handling.

Comment: Nope, that works. That displays the webpage that asks for the first and last name

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think there's no need to add the double quote mark *%22*, nor the plus sign it's not javascript and if you're writing it on the browser url bar, it will parse it for you later on the servlet

Try this: http://localhost:51500/examples/servlets/servlet/RequestParamExample?firstname=x&lastname=y

**EDIT**

After reading the comments i agree, first troubleshoot the mapping and some other issues, it's helpful if you bring some code, problems and/or errors, please read on [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This seems to be the answer. Works. I did not have the %22 in the original url i entered by the way. It was generated automatically when the error came back as a response.

Comment: Then please mark it as right answer to close it and keep clean the site.

Comment: Yep, i just had to wait until it let me decide that it was right. When the guy said "wouldnt work either" its clearly working. I just needed to know how to pass in parameters. I never knew that. Which you showed me. I guess i was not clear enough with my question. The mappings are correct. No need to downvote. Closing